# Which one is correct? two years’ period or two years period?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Which one is correct and more appropriate?

> two years’ period
>
> two years period

why?

Answer (score 4):

It should be

*a two-year period*

*"Two-year"* is functioning as an adjective in this case, but adjectives don't have plural forms in English.